# SQL Server 2008 removing dbo header from tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way of removing `dbo.` header from the visualization of the tables? Something like the old SQL Server 2000 style? I'm working with a database with more than 100 tables and I lose a lot of time finding one of them for doing the work, with the previous DBMS I simply keyed in the initial letter of the table and the system located the element for me, now all the tables begin with dbo and this simple option isn’t available. I was searching on the options for visual configuration but found nothing.

Thanks,
Klueze.

Comment: I don't think so (and [3rd party tools don't offer this either](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/79309/way-to-ignore-specific-schema)). Train your fingers to type `dbo.`...

Comment: What client tool are you seeing this 'visualisation' in? This would be a client tool specific question.